# Percentage based margin using autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to place my subview with a left margin based on the width of the parent view. This sounds simple but I can't figure out how to do it using autolayout.

Logically, I would only need to set the left margin value at a certain percentage value of the parent's width but at the moment, I fail to translate that logic to autolayout.

This is my code at the moment:

```
var view = UIView();
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);

var sview = UIView();
sview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
sview.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor();
//sview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
view.addSubview(sview);

var dict = Dictionary<String, UIView>()
dict["box"] = sview;

var con1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0);
view.addConstraint(con1);

var con2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0.0);
view.addConstraint(con2);

var con3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0);
view.addConstraint(con3);

var con4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0);
view.addConstraint(con4);
```

This is the where the code returns an error:

```
var con2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0.0);
view.addConstraint(con2);
```

Error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint
>   constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]:
>   Invalid pairing of layout attributes'

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this? I just want the left margin to be 0.75% of the parent view's width.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is the **left** of `sview` **to be at some point of the** **left** of `view` and you are writing that you want the left of `sview` to be at some point of the width of `view` which is not a correct pairing of layout attributes as your error says.

Here is what you need to do:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: sview, 
              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 
              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
                 toItem: view, 
              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 
             multiplier: 1, 
               constant: (CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds) * 0.75));
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

I found a great article about Percented based margins: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20170624134422/http://simblestudios.com/blog/development/percentage-width-in-autolayout.html

Or even simpler:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170704113819/http://simblestudios.com/blog/development/easier-percentage-width-in-autolayout.html

[image]

Comment: Links seem to be dead :(

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20170624134422/http://simblestudios.com/blog/development/percentage-width-in-autolayout.html https://web.archive.org/web/20170704113819/http://simblestudios.com/blog/development/easier-percentage-width-in-autolayout.html

Comment: This is beautiful!

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to create a percentage-based margins with auto layout constraints between a subview and its superview. The margin will change dynamically as the size of the superview changes. For example, this is how to create a trailing 10% margin.

1. Create a trailing constraint between your view and its superview.
2. Make sure the first constraint item is the subview and the second item is the superview. This can be done by clicking on the first item drop down and selecting Reverse First and Second Item.
3. Change the constant value of the constraint to zero in the attributes inspector.
4. Change the multiplier value to 0.9.

[image]

The is one problem with this manual approach though - it does not work in right-to-left language, Arabic, for example. Right-to-left layouts require a bit different settings for the constraint but we can not keep both in one storyboard.

Here is a library that I wrote that lets you create percentage-based constraints. It does handle the right-to-left language case.

https://github.com/exchangegroup/PercentageMargin

Comment: I tried this with a subview with top spacing of 10% of superview. Did not seem to work - it just made the subview 0 points from top

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `NSLayoutConstraint` to accept a margin percentage via `@IBInspectable`. Then subscribe to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` to run the calculation and stuff into the `constant` value so it is updated whenever the layout changes.

```
/// Layout constraint to calculate size based on multiplier.
class PercentLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    @IBInspectable var marginPercent: CGFloat = 0

    var screenSize: (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        return (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        guard marginPercent > 0 else { return }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(layoutDidChange),
            name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification,
            object: nil)
    }

    /**
     Re-calculate constant based on orientation and percentage.
     */
    func layoutDidChange() {
        guard marginPercent > 0 else { return }

        switch firstAttribute {
        case .Top, .TopMargin, .Bottom, .BottomMargin:
            constant = screenSize.height * marginPercent
        case .Leading, .LeadingMargin, .Trailing, .TrailingMargin:
            constant = screenSize.width * marginPercent
        default: break
        }
    }

    deinit {
        guard marginPercent > 0 else { return }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

First you specify the new subclass in `Identity Inspector`:
[image]

Then you can use it like this:
[image]

The only caveat I can think of is the constants in the Storyboard are not used at runtime, but instead are overwritten with the percentage based calculation. So it does require some duplicate effort, once to actually layout the views on Storyboard based on points just so you get a sense of what the screen layout looks like, then percentages kick in at runtime.

For more details, check out this article: http://basememara.com/percentage-based-margin-using-autolayout-storyboard/

Answer (score 0):

Along with the Kevin answer you also need to add constraint for the box superview.

```
var view = UIView();
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
    view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
    self.view.addSubview(view);
    var viewObject = ["mainview" : self.view , "view" : view];
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view(==320)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewObject));
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view(==400)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewObject));
```